# Angular 2 - Endless loop in async pipe

Tags: angular, pipe

I`m getting an endless loop when I try to bind a async function like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let i of items">
     <td>{{myAsyncFunc(i) | async}}</td>
</tr>
```

this is the function:

```
private myAsyncFunc(i: string): Promise<string> {
        return Promise.resolve("some");
}
```

I'm doing something wrong? Or this is a bug?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're returning a new Promise from `myAsyncFunc(i: string)` on every call, that's why you get an "endless loop". Try returning the same Promise instance ;-)

The "endless loop" is actually not a traditional endless loop but rather a side-effect of `async` pipe triggering a change detection cycle when its input Promise resolves. On this new change detection cycle, angular will call `myAsyncFunc(i: string)` and get a new Promise to observe, which then resolves the whole thing starts again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... So I have to set the Promise instance on each item? Or how  I return the same instance?

Comment: You would either have to cache the promise for each i (e.g. in a map object) or simply attach the promise to i itself (I personally like having dedicated view models anyway).

Comment: @JohannesRudolph Saved my day :) !

Comment: @JohannesRudolph Is there a simple example for doing this? Still can not figure out how to do this...thanks

Comment: @JohannesRudolph How to return the same instance?

Comment: How can this be the answer when there is no example.

Answer (score 5):

If your async/observable requires you to pass a parameter (e.g., you are inside an ngFor loop) perhaps you can create a custom async pipe for that.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customPipe'
})
export class customPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}

  /**
   * 
   * @param id 
   */
  transform(id: number): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.someService.shouldShow(id);
  }

}
```

And in your template you can call your async pipe as:

```
<td>{{id | customPipe | async}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to use [Memoizee](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memoizee).

You can create a custom decorator to memoize your function as instructed [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-improve-angular-performance-by-just-adding-just-8-characters-877bde708ddd). After that you can just write your function as follows:

```
@memoize()    
private myAsyncFunc(i: string): Promise<string> {
        return Promise.resolve("some");
}
```

This caches the initially returned Promise and when the `async` pipe re-checks the Promise's status it will get the cached Promise not a new one.

Be aware of the caching effects of memoizing a function.

Answer (score -1):

You can check my blogpost on this specific topic, when it strikes our project consuming 5GB od browser RAM :)
It's [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-change-your-angular-app-ram-eating-beast-tomasz-budzi%C5%84ski)

Simplest way to heal this issue is (as already mentioned) don't use function returned promise direct in template: `{{ getPromise(id) | async }}` but store this promise in controller (`.ts` file) and refer to it in view.
In addition, this can be healed by changing change detection settings to `push-pull`, but in my opinion it's brings way more evil than good.