# Infinite loop when using *ngFor with async pipe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, pipe

My problem is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265716/angular-2-endless-loop-in-async-pipe).

In `foo.component.html`:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-container *ngIf="(fooFunc(item.property) | async) as element">
        {{ element | json }}
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

In `foo.component.ts`:

```js
fooFunc(foo: any) {
  return this.fooService.fooServiceFunc(foo).pipe(
    take(1),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
}
```

The `fooServiceFunc` in `fooService` will return only one `Observable` at one time.

My problem is that now my app fires infinite requests (after the whole `items` array has been iterated, it will fire the request again from beginning, over and over), which seems to be a side-effect of `async` pipe which is announced in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41265906/10684507). But I still cannot figure out how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save you shared stream to variable and use the variable in template

```
data$ = forkJoin(
  this.items.map(item => this.fooService.fooServiceFunc(item.property).pipe(
    map(fetchResult => ({ fetchResult, item })
  ))
)
```

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">
    <ng-container *ngIf="item.fetchResults">
        {{ item.fetchResults | json }}
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Now you create new stream for each `item`, and each query runs change detection, whitch runs queries again.

My advice: Try to avoid function calls in templates, functions in template executes when changeDetection for current component runs (AsyncPipe run change detection by each value in the input stream).

Comment: Sorry for my English... I can give you relevant articles if you need more details.

Comment: Very appericiate for your answer! I think it will be nice for you to provide the reference link since others who see this question may need this.

And I found that, since the `map` syntax used in your answer, the `data$` has already iterate the whole `items` and becomes an array, too. So, there is no need to use `*ngFor="let item of items"` in html template, which means the code in html should be things like this:
```<ng-container *ngFor="let foo of (data$ | async)">
    {{ foo | json }}
</ng-container>```

Comment: yes you're right, I updated answer with your corrections.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, would you please give out the reference links? I do want to know more details.

Comment: for understand why fetch inside of template triggers infinity loop, first at all you need to understand how change detection works, you can read this article for that: https://blog.angular-university.io/how-does-angular-2-change-detection-really-work/

Comment: Thanks, I'll read this. You said that "avoid function calls in templates", now, imho, seems that there is no way to use function calls with `async` pipe in templates without causing this "infinite loop" problem. Binding the function to a varaible seems to be the only way to fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193531/discussion-between-izmaylovdev-and-funkid).