# Async function returning promise, but calling function not resolving

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have researched other similar items here so far without result and obviously need to understand promises better but I am struggling here.

I have an Ionic 4/Angular 8 project with and Azure based back-end.
I am trying to get the pages to display images from the Azure storage which requires a key appended to the url.

To avoid having the 'check key, get a new one if expired, append to url' code in every page, I thought I'd make a service function to do it. But though I can get it to work, the calling function doesn't appear to be waiting on the '.then' and so I am getting undefined. (I think). Ideally, I would like the service to just return a string

The service function (with some comments and debug o/p) I have is this:

```
   // Ideally I'd like to just return a string here ---v
 // v- but the async nature needs async return type ??
 async getStorageURLWithKey(url: string): Promise<string> {
  const nowplus5 =  addMinutes(Date.now(), 5); // 5 mins to give some leeway
  console.log(nowplus5);
  console.log(url);
  console.log(this.azurekey);
  if (!this.azurekey || isBefore( this.azurekey.Expires, nowplus5 )) {
    console.log('Getting new Key');
    const keyObj = await this.getAzureKeyServer().toPromise();
    await this.saveAzureKeyStore(keyObj);
    return url + keyObj.Key; // Return the url with the new Key
  } else {
    console.log('Key is valid' + this.azurekey.Expires);
    const rval = new Promise<string>(function(res) {
      res(url + this.azurekey.Key);
    });
    return rval ; // Key is in time so return it with url
  }
 }
```

My calling function is this:

```
getBizImg(): string {
  console.log('GetBizImg');
  if (this.business.Id) {  // We have a Business Object
    this.userService.getStorageURLWithKey(this.business.ImageURL).then((url) => {
      console.log(url);
      return url;
    }, reject => {
      console.log('Rejected:' + reject);
    });
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

If I call the getBizImg function from say ngOninit, it is getting back undefined before the getBizImg - console.log(url) line.

Here's the ngOninit:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const imageurl = this.getBizImg();
  console.log(imageurl);
}
```

Really the call should be coming from the page:

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-img [src]="getBizImg()" ></ion-img>
</ion-content>
```

But i have commented this out till I can resolve this issue. Otherwise it gets into a seemingly endless loop.

If I turn the getBizImg() into an async function and await the call and return a promise, it works fine -if I modify my ngInit to:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getBizImg().then((wibble) => {
    console.log(wibble);
  });
}
```

and the getBizImg function to:

```
async getBizImg(): Promise<string> {
  console.log('GetBizImg ID= ' + this.business.Id);
   if (this.business.Id) {  // We have a Business Object
     const url = await this.userService.getStorageURLWithKey(this.business.ImageURL);
     console.log(url);
     return url;
   } else {
     return '';
   }
 }
```

But that won't get me the simple string I need for the HTML.

I'm not sure if I am missing something (probably) obvious...

**** Edit update****
I have tried changing to the fully async and including the angular async pipe:

```
<ion-content padding>
  BIZ IMAGE
<ion-img [src]="getBizImg() | async" ></ion-img>
```

I also tried to just show the string with:`URL is: {{ getBizImg() | async }}`

But it gets into a (seemingly endless loop). It is strange though, because it is getting to the this.getAzureKeyServer() function but I am not hitting a breakpoint that I have set in my server code at the GetKey API call.

This set me on a different path to check the page function some more. I took out the calls to the back end to just return a string like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
  BIZ IMAGE
  URL is: {{ getBizImg() | async }}
</ion-content>

  async getBizImg(): Promise<string> {
    console.log('GetBizImg ID= ' + this.business.Id);
    if (this.business.Id) {  // We have a Business Object
      const url = 'wibble'; // this.business.ImageURL;
      // const url = await this.userService.getStorageURLWithKey(this.business.ImageURL);
      console.log(url);
      return url;
    } else {
      console.log('invalid id');
      return 'invalid id';
    }
  }
```

... and that just gets into an endless loop too, so I am thinking there is something more fundamental going on... I mean have I made some kind of schoolboy error here?

Comment: I think this might help me, Im going to investigate..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265716/angular-2-endless-loop-in-async-pipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your async getBizImg() is right. you could do it this way

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.getBizImg().then((wibble) => {
    console.log(wibble);
    // just add here this.urlImage = wibble
  });
}
```

on your component add a urlImage.
and in the html

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-img *ngIf="urlImage" [src]="urlImage" ></ion-img>
</ion-content>
```

or if you want to call it from the html, I'am not sure but try the asyncPipe https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-img [src]="getBizImg() | async" ></ion-img>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks med, you were right ... My issue wasn't in my code so much as the approach and a mis-understanding of angular. It became clearer when I removed the calls to the back end (probably should have done that in the first place - but wasn't aware of this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265716/angular-2-endless-loop-in-async-pipe).

Answer (score 1):

`getBizImg()` never returns a URL since you only return it in the callback of the `getStorageURLWithKey()` promise.

Return that promise (and change the method type to `Promise<string>` and use the async pipe to display it:

```js
getBizImg(): string {
  console.log('GetBizImg');
  if (this.business.Id) {  // We have a Business Object
    // return here
    return this.userService.getStorageURLWithKey(this.business.ImageURL).then((url) => {
      console.log(url);
      return url;
    }, reject => {
      console.log('Rejected:' + reject);
    });
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

```
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-img [src]="getBizImg() | async"></ion-img>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I have put an **Edit Update** in the ext above.. simplified it right down. So I think my problem is to do with the async pipe.. does it need setting up?

Comment: Solved it by stripping back and realising the problem wasn't so much the code but the approach and a mis-understand of angulars change management - see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265716/angular-2-endless-loop-in-async-pipe, But thank you anyway.